# How can I use local storage to maintain dropdown menu state?

Tags: javascript, css, menu

I'm trying to make a simple menu and have it expand downwards and then on reload keep it expanded/closed, depending on what the user had before the reload. I know there's a html localstorage function for javascript, but I am uncertain on this could be implemented to my code. Needless to say, I am very new to particularly Javascript.

Here's my code,

```
<p class="portfolio_menuOpt collapsible">
Series 
</p>
<div class="sub_menu_collapsible">
<p class="portfolio_menuOpt_Sub">
        Feral - Mustang 69' 
    </p>
    <p class="portfolio_menuOpt_Sub ">
        Mnemosyne - Morris Minor 1000
    </p>
</div> 

var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
```

How can I achieve this? And could I possibly empty this localstorage after some time has gone (and also make sure just one collapsible can be used AT A TIME?). Thanks a bunch for any help.

Comment: You can do all the things you've asked about. Have you tried? Your question should contain your effort and the *specific* problem you're facing. If you do some reading on  local storage I think you'll find it fairly simple.

Comment: Heyo. I'm aware that I can do this yes, I just can't figure it out in the context of my code. Putting it in an if statement works yes, but I'm not sure how to progress beyond making sure if it's actually indeed true/false in regards to opened or not.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is change variable in local storage on dropdown click. End after every reload page get this variable from local storage to know, if the dropdown should be open or close.

Here is a code to change/set local storage variable:

```
localStorage.setItem('dropdownToggle', 'true');
```

Here is a code to get local storage variable:

```
localStorage.getItem('dropdownToggle');
```

Also you can set timeout and after that remove variable from local storage:

```
localStorage.removeItem('dropdownToggle');
```

or just clean it all

```
localStorage.clear();
```

If you have additional questions ask it in the comment, i will glad to help you out.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I've tried with these functions, but I'm not sure how to figure out the logical side of it.. I can set the function to say true or remove the storage (which though does affect every collapsible div as the script is made to work for multiple collapsibles) but I'm not sure how to implement it in my code to actually have the div expand if it's true. I tried putting if statement inside content.style.maxheight part but I really can't figure this out..

Comment: I think you can set display to 'none' if the value local storage variable  is false, and 'block' if the value of local storage variable is true. That is how you can show and hide your drop down menu.

Comment: It's not the intent to hide or show it.. but rather to make it expand or not expand. I need to trigger it to expand using the script that I have.